Blend GSC and GA4 data inflated numbers
I am trying to blend together Google Search Console (GSC) and Google Analytics 4 (GA4) by page in Looker Studio.
If I create a table based on GSC data, for page x, I have:

297,084 impressions
30,986 clicks

If I create a table based on GA4 data, for page x, I have:

34,091 sessions
24,654 views

However, when I blend the data together, for page x, I have:

297,084 impressions
30,986 clicks
38,330 sessions
41,355 views

It doesn't seem to make any difference if I do a LEFT, INNER or FULL join based on page URL.
literally joining the two (GSC and GA4) just on page URL

Pages are identical in each dataset (tracking parameters removed), i.e.
www.website.com/page
The GA4 data for the page is a lot higher than it should be, and I don't understand why this is happening. Any ideas?


How are you connecting it at the finer level. Like per user/session?
Is the GA4 date filtered by organic Google search?

@TonyMcCreath added an image of the join, literally blending the datasets with page URL only.

the blend seems to add 10.6% to each GA4 metric number

The issue arises when using the "New User" metric in the GA4 Blend Table.
For some unknown reason (possibly related to consent mode), using this metric in combination with other metrics such as view and session results in data changes.
To address this issue, you can obtain consistent numbers by either removing the "New User" metric from the Blended Data or adding this metric to the GA4 Native Table.
